# Train autoencoder in script mode on AWS sagemaker

Tags: keras, amazon-sagemaker, autoencoder

I want to train an autoencoder using keras where X_train is mxn matrix and y_train is also mxn matrix.
for Examaple

```
X_train = np.array(([1, 2], 
               [3, 4]))
y_train = np.array(([5, 6], 
               [7, 8]))
```

I concatenate two matrix in `train_set` and save into one file `training.npy`

```
train_set = np.concatenate([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
print(train_set)
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

Later I save it to S3

```
training_path_input = sess.upload_data('/tmp/training.npy', key_prefix=prefix+'/training')
```

Now when I fit the model

```
model.fit({'train': training_path_input })
```

I wonder how estimator will find index for `X_train` and `y_train` since `y_train` is not a vector unlike other cases. Is there any way to specify this in `fit()` method.

Or is there any alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The fit method does 2 things: (1) copy your data from `training_path_input` (on S3) to `/opt/ml/input/data/<channel>` in the SageMaker training instance (`/opt/ml/input/data/train` in your case) and (2) launching the code with any hyperparameter you specified. You need to make sure that your training code knows how to read the type of files you're copying to the machine. Your training code must include code that will read locally the copied files.